# How to elegantly detect when all mongo inserts have completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Ive written and basic Node app (my first) to insert many csv rows into mongo (items array in the code below). Once all items have been inserted the db connection should be closed and the program exited.

The issue ive been working with is figuring out when to close the db connection once all inserts have returned a result. Ive gotten it working by counting all of the insert result callbacks but to me this feels clunky. I know one improvement I could make is to batch the inserts via an array to the insert function but ill still need to have my code be aware of when all inserts have completed (assuming it would be bad to insert 100k items in one query). Is there and better way (my code feels hacky) to do this?

Hack part...

```
function (err, result) {
    queryCompletedCount++;
    if (err) console.log(err);

    //Not sure about doing it this way
    //Close db once all queries have returned a result
    if (queryCompletedCount === items.length) {
        db.close();
        console.log("Finish inserting data: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

Full insert code

```
MongoClient.connect(dbConnectionURL, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error connecting to DB: " + err);
    } else {
        var productCollection = db.collection('products');
        console.log("Connected to DB");
        console.log("Start inserting data: " + new Date());

        var queryCompletedCount = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            productCollection.insert([{
                manufacturerCode: null,
                name: items[i].name,
                description: null
            }], function (err, result) {
                queryCompletedCount++;
                if (err) console.log(err);

                //Not sure about doing it this way
                //Close db once all queries have returned a result
                if (queryCompletedCount === items.length) {
                    db.close();
                    console.log("Finish inserting data: " + new Date());
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You do realize that `insert` accepts an array of documents to insert? You don't have to do that in a loop...

Comment: Yep but I dont think its a good idea to pass a 100k array to the insert function. Ill probably change this to batch 100 at a time as mentioned above

Comment: Why? That's what it has been designed for. If you use a loop and 100k separate calls to `insert()`, how is that gonna be faster/more efficient? In any case, before you write elaborate batching code, try the straight-forward way.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about realizing this issue with `async` module like this:

```
async = require('async')
async.eachSeries(items, function (item, next) {
  productCollection.insert(productCollection.insert(
      [{
        manufacturerCode: null,
        name: item.name,
        description: null
      }], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        next();
      })
  )
}, function () {
  // this will be called after all insertion completed
  db.close();
  console.log("Finish inserting data: " + new Date());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is MongoDB's [`Write Concern`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/), configured in the strictest way.

There are two levels of `Write Concern`. The first is the write mode, in which case the query returns only if the result is written to the configured number of `mongo` instances. In your case I suppose there is a single instance, but for future you may configure it as `"w": "majority"`. The second level is the `Journal` concern, where by setting `"j": 1` your query will return only when the data is written into the `journal`.

So in your case you best `Write Concern` configuration might be `{"w": "majority", "j": 1}`. Just add it as the last argument of your `insert` statement.